# How to rotate a 3D image by a random angle in python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I'm using a set of 32x32x32 grayscale images and I want to apply random rotations on the images as a part of data augmentation while training a CNN by tflearn + tensorflow. I was using the following code to do so:

```
    # Real-time data preprocessing
    img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
    img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()


    # Real-time data augmentation
    img_aug = ImageAugmentation()
    img_aug.add_random_rotation(max_angle=360.)

    # Input data
    with tf.name_scope('Input'):
        X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, image_size, 
    image_size, image_size, num_channels), name='x-input')
        Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, label_cnt), name='y-input')


    # Convolutional network building
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 32, 1],
                 placeholder = X,
                 data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                 data_augmentation=img_aug)
```

(I'm using a combination of tensorflow and tflearn to be able to use the features from both, so please bear with me. Let me know if something is wrong with the way I'm using placeholders, etc.)

I found that using the **add_random_rotation** (which itself uses scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate) treats the third dimension of my grayscale images as channels (like RGB channels) and rotates all 32 images of the third dimension by a random angel around z-axis(treats my 3D image as a 2D image with 32 channels). But I want the image to be rotated in the space (around all three axes). Do you have any idea how can I do that? Is there a function or package for easily rotating the 3D images in space?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more difficult to incorporate in the `ImageAugmentation()` but the `scipy.ndimage.rotate` function by default rotates 3D images correctly and takes the axes argument which specifies which specify the plane of rotation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html). Rotating around the first axis (x) means you pass `axes=(1,2)`, to rotate around the second axis (y) use`axes=(0,2)`

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion and came up with the following function to rotate a batch of 3D images randomly around axes with the specified max angle (I'm posting it here in case someone needs it):

Comment: @kmader, does the order of the axes parameters play a role? i.e. is `axes=(1,2)` equal to `axes=(2,1)`?

Answer (score 11):

```
def random_rotation_3d(batch, max_angle):
    """ Randomly rotate an image by a random angle (-max_angle, max_angle).

    Arguments:
    max_angle: `float`. The maximum rotation angle.

    Returns:
    batch of rotated 3D images
    """
    size = batch.shape
    batch = np.squeeze(batch)
    batch_rot = np.zeros(batch.shape)
    for i in range(batch.shape[0]):
        if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
            image1 = np.squeeze(batch[i])
            # rotate along z-axis
            angle = random.uniform(-max_angle, max_angle)
            image2 = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(image1, angle, mode='nearest', axes=(0, 1), reshape=False)

            # rotate along y-axis
            angle = random.uniform(-max_angle, max_angle)
            image3 = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(image2, angle, mode='nearest', axes=(0, 2), reshape=False)

            # rotate along x-axis
            angle = random.uniform(-max_angle, max_angle)
            batch_rot[i] = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(image3, angle, mode='nearest', axes=(1, 2), reshape=False)
            #                print(i)
        else:
            batch_rot[i] = batch[i]
    return batch_rot.reshape(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate any 3D image around the center and keep it in the center use scipy affine_transform using offset as follows:

```
# create a 3D image
image = np.random.random((20,20,20))
# output shape
output_shape = np.array(image.shape)
# rotation matrix around z axis
theta = 0.01
cosine = np.cos(theta)
sinus = np.sin(theta)
M = np.array([[cosine, -sinus, 0],
                         [sinus, cosine, 0],
                         [0, 0, 1]])
# offset
offset = (np.array(image.shape)-M.dot(np.array(output_shape)))
offset = offset/2.0 # it is important
# affine transformation
f_data = affine_transform(np.asarray(image), np.asarray(M),
                              output_shape=output_shape, offset=offset)
```